# Styling components programmatically in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

try this and the label is not visible. Any help on styling components?

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    Component label = new Label();

    Style styleLabel= new Style();
    styleLabel.setPadding(Component.RIGHT, 10);
    styleLabel.setPadding(Component.TOP, 10);
    styleLabel.setPadding(Component.LEFT, 10);
    styleLabel.setMargin(Component.LEFT, 10);

    label.setSelectedStyle(styleLabel);
    label.setUnselectedStyle(styleLabel);

    hi.addComponent(label);
    hi.show();
}
```

Comment: your label has no text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the label text or an icon would help... This has nothing to do with the style. e.g.:

```
   Component label = new Label("Hi");
```

FYI, its better to style as:

```
  label.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(Component.RIGHT, 10);
```

Rather than allocating your own `Style` object. There are some "niche" complexities in that approach especially when reusing the `Style` object.